# Odoo, user portal may not see worked hours

Tags: odoo

How can i disbale in odoo online that the portal use does not see the worked hours of the shared project? i've already edited the code of the task list view, but can't find the column for the worked hours

Also can't find where it's getting called

Remove the worked hours column from the user portal page